# Jmeter kafka producer load test send string delimited Json

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to send json with string delimited one
for e.g

```
"carrierId":"XXX",
"eventProcessedTS":1618261255871,
"eventTS":1618261255871,
"deviceId":"XXX",
"event":  "{\"deviceDetailsDataModel\":{\"eventDateTime\":1618261255871,\"vin\":\"XXXX\",\"deviceTimeZone\":\"XXXX\",\"deviceId\":\"XXXXX\"}}"
}
```

but when I look at the kafka consumer
I am receiving the message as

````
"carrierId":"XXX",
"eventProcessedTS":1618261255871,
"eventTS":1618261255871,
"deviceId":"XXX",
"event":  "{"deviceDetailsDataModel":{"eventDateTime":1618261255871,"vin":"XXXX","deviceTimeZone":"XXXX","deviceId":"XXXXX"}}"
}```

without string delimited.
I have created this as JsonObject and convert event object alone to string using  event.toString() in my JSR223sampler but Still, it's not working. is it a limitation?  I am using kafkaclient 2.7.0
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear which "Jmeter kafka producer" you're using, out of box JMeter doesn't provide any Kafka load testing capabilities, if you're using a plugin like [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) or [kafkameter](https://github.com/BrightTag/kafkameter) you should reach out to JMeter plugins developers and/or maintainers with this question.

Also be aware that you can always implement Kafka producer using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy code](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), example code would be something like:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

def props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", "your_JSON_here");

producer.close();
```

This way you will get confidence that JMeter sending your JSON "as is" without any eventual transformations introduced by the plugins

More information: [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)

Comment: I am implementing kafka producer using JSR223 sampler and groovy as suggested above and used the link you attached as the reference to build my json